# UPDATE then SELECT data MySQL to textBox to write in NFC

Tags: c#, mysql, nfc

i have some problem. first i want to update data from MySQL database then pick that updated data into my NFC Card. and in the same time the data that inserted into NFC is picked afted the data has been updated not before data was updated. i have assumption maybe i cannot use select after update then write nfc. and lastly, every change on the card always refresh every action that i have been doing. i was using [h4kbas NFCReader](https://github.com/h4kbas/NfcReader) for interaction in NFC Devices. this my code

```
 if (NFC.Connect())
            {
                txtUID.Text = NFC.GetCardUID(); //displaying on text block

                try
                {
                    establish_connection();
                    query = "UPDATE tsaldo SET saldo = saldo + ('" + txtJumlahSaldo.Text + "' / 2) WHERE uid = '" + txtUID.Text + "';";
                    cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        string cvti = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                        
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cvti) == false)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                query = "SELECT saldo FROM tsaldo WHERE uid = '" + txtUID.Text + "';";
                                cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                                mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                                if (mdr.Read())
                                {
                                    txtJumlahSaldo.Text = mdr.GetString("saldo");
                                    NFC.WriteBlock(txtJumlahSaldo.Text, "5");
                                        
                                    if (NFC.Connect())
                                    {
                                        txtUID.Text = NFC.GetCardUID();
                                        string str = ByteTostring(NFC.ReadBlock("5"));
                                        txtJumlahSaldo.Text = str;

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show("Gagal membaca data kartu");
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   txtJumlahSaldo.Text = "";
                                   MessageBox.Show("Berhasil menulis data di kartu");
                                }
                               
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Pengisian saldo berhasil");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Gagal melakukan pendaftaran");
            }
            this.Close();
```

i try searcing for update then select but some give example select then update, not the opposite. hope some one can telling me where i was wrong or help me fix this code and give some explanation where i was wrong. thx

Comment: Please read http://Bobby-tables.com - it will help prevent aproblem you're causing in your code that is much, much bigger

Comment: hey @CaiusJard , sorry for long reply. thx for u r help. i wll try learning in link u give me